# Pre-set Formulas in Validation and alerts?

Tags: orbeon

I'am using Orbeon Forms CE edition. Is there any option to select pre-set formulas for input fields in form builder? In email field, when I select formula in validation I am writing my condition or regex to validate the form data, is there any option to add validation conditions and regex in Dropdown data rather than writing...

Answer (score 0):

You can define those validations as simple types in an XML schema, for instance using regular expressions. Then you can attach your schema to the form in Form Builder, and those simple types will show up in a dropdown in the *Control Settings* dialog, in the *Validations and Alerts* tab. However, this feature is only available in Orbeon Forms PE. For more on this, see [schema support](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/xml-schema-support).